# How to adjust image content mode?

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview, cell

I have collectionView with images and labels. As you can see that the only "Home" image looks fine, the others cut from sides. Can someone please tell me what is the problem and teach me how can I fix that?

[image]

I've played with contentMode, but it didn't work for me.

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How are you setting the constraints for imageView?I think you need to change the width

Comment: if you increase the width, then what is the behaviour?

Comment: All the same, nothing changed. I changed width and height before - no success

Comment: Played with constraints as well

Comment: Are you showing the images in a collectionview?

Comment: Yep. Horizontal scroll

Comment: Have you tried changing the size of item in collection view?

Comment: Yes, I did. All stays the same